# Как при преобразовании tgs в gif поставить белый фон?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, изображения

Написал программу для конвертации .tgs файла в webm, но видео всегда получается на черном фоне, как я понимаю при чтении файла надо что-то добавлять в layers в tgs файле, но не уверен, использую библиотеку lottie.

```
import os
import cv2
import logging
from lottie.parsers.tgs import parse_tgs,parse_tgs_json
from lottie.exporters.video import export_video
from PIL import Image
from lottie.objects import Animation
def convert_tgs_to_webm(tgs_file, gif_file):

    try:
        
        animation = parse_tgs_json(tgs_file)

        animation = Animation.load(animation)
        export_video(animation, gif_file,'webm')
        
        return True
    except Exception:
        logging.exception("Error occurred while converting TGS to GIF.")
        return False
```

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю код, lottie для экспорта видео использует OpenCV, а он вроде принципиально не поддерживает прозрачность. Вероятно, придётся экспортировать кадры по отдельности (например `export_png` если в нём работает прозрачность) и как-то вручную собирать эти кадры в видео нужного формата

Comment: @andreymal, нет, lottie не использует opencv, я просто забыл убрать. Эта библиотека относится к другой функции, я после скачивания видео разбиваю его на кадры, но с ней всё впорядке

Comment: Нет, lottie [точно использует](https://gitlab.com/mattbas/python-lottie/-/blob/master/lib/lottie/exporters/video.py#L4) opencv и ваш код тут ни при чём

Comment: @andreymal, понял, спасибо за подсказку